# BigQuery - query to find what groups and members of those for a specified dataset or all datasets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm incredibly new to BigQuery.  I'm on a mission to document who has access to each of our datasets.  The manual way of copying and pasting group names and then members of that group into a google sheets document would take a very long time and seems unnecessary.  I have to believe there is a way to query a dataset to find this information.

Would anyone have any suggestions for something like this?
Select datasetName, group, groupMember, roles from x
where datasetName = "myDataSet"

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Bigquery doesn't bring any way to approach this via standard/legacy SQL language statements as [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs) (*Identity and Access Management*) related information is not promoted/published across Bigquery data volumes, in fact not included in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` metadata [inventory](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro), thus you can't write a query that simply fetches this data.

In particular, you can use `bq` [command-line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-command-line) tool, this Python binary leverages interaction with [Biqquery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries-overview), that might give a chance to explore Dataset related information, including the access control entries. Given said this, focusing on `bq show` command you can write the plain bash loop fetching up the dataset metadata along the particular GCP project:

```
my_project="<Project_ID>";ds=$(bq ls --project_id=$my_project | awk '{print $1}' | tail +3); for ds in $ds; do bq show $my_project:$ds; done
```